# javascript http request callback handling

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been using Jquery Ajax function from long time & recently thought to move back to pure javascript for deep learning & increase performance.

I am using following method to get response of http request.

```
Ajax(baseurl + datastring, myFunction1);
```

with following callback based function

```
function Ajax(url, cFunction) 
{
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            cFunction(this);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

then using callback in this function

```
function myFunction1(xhttp) {
  alert(xhttp);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  var myObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xhttp));
  alert(myObj);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp;
}
```

in 1st alert of callback function "**myFunction1**" I am getting response as **[object XMLHttpRequest]** in 2nd alert response is **[object Object]**.
My question is though attached image showing that record is getting inserted successfully in database but why i am not able to get json output responsetext element **Status** or **message**?

[image]

console log with `console.log(xhttp);`
[image]

**PHP script**

```
<?php
require_once "Local.php";
require_once "class.db.php";
$dbc = new DB();

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) { $_POST[$key] = $dbc->filter( $value ); }

    $sfn = $dbc->escape($_POST['sfn']);
    $ssn = $dbc->escape($_POST['ssn']);
    $smn = $dbc->escape($_POST['smn']);
    $sg = $dbc->escape($_POST['sg']);
    $sem = $dbc->escape($_POST['sem']);
    $spass = $dbc->escape($_POST['spass']);

    $check_user = array('email' => $sem);    
    $exists = $dbc->exists( 'tablename', 'email',  $check_user );   
    if( $exists )
    {
        $response['status'] = 'failure';
        $response['message'] = 'Email ID you are trying to use is already occupied by someone else.';   
    }
    else
    {
        $salt = generateSalt();
        $hash = hash_hmac("sha256", $spass, $salt);

        $names = array('fname' => $sfn, 'lname' => $ssn, 'mobile_no' => $smn, 'gender' => $sg, 'email' => $sem, 'salt' => $salt, 'hash' => $hash );
        $add_query = $dbc->insert('tablename', $names);
        if($add_query)
        {               
            $_SESSION['username'] = $sfn;

            $response['status'] = 'success';
            $response['message'] = 'Succesful Registration';
        }else{
            $response['status'] = 'failure';
            $response['message'] = 'Something unexpected happened while processing your request. Please try once again.';   
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert()` prints the string representation of the arguments - hence if you pass an object, you'll get `[object Object]`

you can use the `JSON.stringify()` inside alert to get proper output

Better way is to `console.log` the result rather than using `alert`

**Addition**

Check this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rp6d34uo/) showing the right output which in the fiddle's case should be a blank object.

Comment: I tried following (1) console.log('this.response = ' + JSON.stringify(this.response)); & that's showing "this.response = undefined" (2) console.log('xhttp = ' + JSON.stringify(xhttp)); & that's showing "xhttp = {}" (3) var myObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xhttp));   console.log('myObj = ' + myObj); & that's showing "myObj = [object Object]".

Comment: you need to `console.log(xhttp.response)`. Also console.log('myObj = ' + myObj) will give object object as it converts the entire thing to a string

Comment: console.log(xhttp.response) is showing "xhttp.response = "

Comment: function myFunction1(xhttp) {
  console.log('xhttp.response = ' +  xhttp.response)
}

Comment: Please use comma insted of plus `function myFunction1(xhttp) { console.log('xhttp.response = ', xhttp.response) } `

Comment: Can you just do `console.log(xhttp)` and tell the result

Comment: refer console log with console.log(xhttp); 2nd picture

Comment: Please do a jsfiddle with your code. You can simulate ajax call. I never experienced such a behavior.

Comment: I have added my PHP scripts since it seems there is some error in parsing the information. using script directly by manually providing variables shows no error in script.